# Trying to click all HTML elements in a web page

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Selenium and Beautiful Soup to click, and expand, all toggle elements in a single web page.  My code looks like this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
chromedriver = "C:\Users\rs\Downloads\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
url='http://www.coprporate-site.com'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('next').click()
```

I'm guessing it should be something like that.  By default, items appear like this:

```
<pan-icon class="a6z-dynamic-tree-node-toggle a6z-dynamic-tree-node-toggle-collapsed" size="treeCtrl.nodeArrowIconSize" icon="sort-descending" role="button"> </pan-icon>
```

Each object has a small triangle next to it.  I'm trying to loop through all items that are in the 'toggle-collapsed' state and change each to 'toggle'.  I think the code should look like this, below.

```
<pan-icon class="a6z-dynamic-tree-node-toggle" size="treeCtrl.nodeArrowIconSize" icon="sort-descending" role="button"> </pan-icon>
```

How can I loop through all these specific HTML elements, as described above, and change each one from 'toggle-collapsed' to 'toggle'?  TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium's WebDriver package has several [methods](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) which allow you to fetch all elements in DOM. One of such methods is `find_elements_by_class_name`. Loop through each element and expand it, ideally the way the human user would - through clicking. Thus, your code could look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
chromedriver = "C:\Users\rs\Downloads\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
url='http://www.coprporate-site.com'
driver.get(url)
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('a6z-dynamic-tree-node-toggle-collapsed'):
    element.click()
```

If you need to check whether the class name itself contains 'toggle-collapsed' substring, you could use `find_elements_by_xpath` with `contains` attribute in the XPath, e.g.

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(r"\\*[contains(@class, 'toggle-collapsed')]"):
    element.click()
```